# pgAdmin: How to see complete value in a cell in output

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have a query which gives me the large output value in the output cell. But the problem is that for reading I need to drag the column and see the value and after some range the values are not displaying instead it's showing me `(...)`. 
After copying the value also I am unable to get the whole set of value.

[image]

[image]

**Question**: How can I see the whole set of value from the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a setting for that in the options: `Max characters per column` - useful when dealing with big columns.

Details:

- [Why are query results shortened in pgAdmin 1.18.1?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/52926/3684)

[More in the manual here.](http://pgadmin.org/docs/1.20/options-query_tool.html)

Comment: After setting `Max characters per column`, In one column I am getting blank values but after I copied that and pasted it's giving all values but not showing in the output. Any help will be appreciate.  Thanks :)

Comment: In that column I mean which is showing blank it consist of `5388` columns in a single column or cell.

Comment: @MAK: Leading line breaks maybe?

Comment: Yup! Exactly, that is the issue. I used `E '\n'` to break column into lines. But is that not possible to shown in single row?

Comment: @MAK: Its in the nature of line breaks to start a new line. :) You can increase the height of the grid to *see* data. Or you could modify the query to replace line breaks with spaces or whatever. I wouldn't know any option to convert line breaks for the pgAdmin display automatically. You could start another question for this ...